# Script to find and auto-disable interfaces on Cisco switches with either no traffic no traffic older than 4 weeks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python, the script below provides the desired output and completes the task as required. I would like to know if there is any better ways of completing what I have written and any ways of speeding up the process?

Thank you for looking.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import sys


# **************************************************************** Functions ***
def add_traffic( traffic, detail_interface ):

            global disable
            global traffic_count

            interface = detail_interface.split()

            if traffic.strip() == no_traffic:
                disable.append( [ interface[ 0 ], traffic.strip() ] )
                return interface[ 0 ]
            else:
                traffic_split = traffic.split( ', ' )
                if check_traffic_date( traffic_split[ 0 ] ) == bool( True ):
                    disable.append( [ interface[ 0 ], traffic.strip() ] )
                    return interface[ 0 ]

def check_traffic_date( traffic ):

            traffic     = traffic.strip().split( ' ' )
            data_period = traffic[ 2 ]

            if data_period.find( 'y' ) > 0:
                years = data_period.split( 'y' )
                years = int( years[ 0 ] )

                if years >= 1:
                    return bool( True )

            elif data_period.find( 'w' ) > 0:
                weeks = data_period.split( 'w' )
                weeks = int( weeks[ 0 ] )
                    if weeks >= 4:
                        return bool( True )
            else:
                return bool( False )

           
def check_switch( output, user_disable ):

            for i in range( 0, len( output ) ):
                # Ignore any interfaces that are currently connected
                if output[ i ].find( '(connected)' ) != -1:
                     pass

                 # Ignore any interfaces that are disabled/shutdown
                 elif output[ i ].find( '(disabled)' ) != -1:
                     pass
                 
                 # Ignore any interfaces that are disabled/shutdown
                 elif output[ i ].find( 'GigabitEthernet0/0' ) != -1:
                     pass

                 elif output[ i ].find( 'GigabitEthernet' ) != -1:
                     unused_interface = add_traffic( output[ i + 1 ], output[ i ] )
                     if user_disable.upper() == 'Y':
                         auto_disable( unused_interface )

                 elif output[ i ].find( 'FastEthernet' ) != -1:
                     unused_interface = add_traffic( output[ i + 1 ], output[ i ] )
                     if user_disable.upper() == 'Y':
                         auto_disable( unused_interface )

def auto_disable( interface ):

            if str( interface ) != 'None':
                config_commands = [ "int " + str( interface ), "shutdown" ]
                net_connect.send_config_set( config_commands )





# **************************************************************** Main Content ***
platform         = 'cisco_ios'
username         = 'username'
password         = 'password'
ip_hosts         = open( r"ip_list.txt","r" )

# Pre-defined variables
no_traffic       = "Last input never, output never, output hang never"
traffic_count    = []
disable          = []

# Ask whether auto disable is to be used
user_disable = input( 'Would you like to auto disable unused interfaces? (Y/N): ' )

for host in ip_hosts:
            net_connect   = ConnectHandler( device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password )
            output        = net_connect.send_command( 'show interface | include FastEthernet|GigabitEthernet|Last in' )
            output        = output.splitlines()
            check_switch( output, user_disable )

print( '###########################################################################################' )
print( '#                                 Cisco Command Output                                    #' )
print( '###########################################################################################' )

for i in disable:
            print( i )
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 37, that I assume is a copy-paste error (`if weeks >=4:` is over-indented)

Comment: Also, throughout `check_switch` you have an extra space (from the first `elif` on) in the indent, which is also a syntax error

Comment: Please checkout [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. Following it will make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I believe the indentation has been messed up with the copy paste.

Is anyone able to provide information on the code itself, better techniques to use and anything that may make the code more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid globals

Try deleting these:

```
        global disable
        global traffic_count
```

and passing them in either as parameters to `add_traffic` or as members on a class.

### Booleans

```
bool( True )
```

is redundant and equivalent to `True`, but you can further shorten that `if` to

```
if check_traffic_date(traffic_split[0]):
```

### Named unpacking

Consider converting

```
        traffic     = traffic.strip().split( ' ' )
        data_period = traffic[ 2 ]
```

to something like

```
foo, bar, data_period = traffic.strip().split(' ')
```

This works well if you understand what is expected at each position. You can splat-unpack `, *_` as the last entry if you don't care about trailing entries.

### String membership

```
        if data_period.find( 'y' ) > 0:
```

might be a bug. If you're intent on checking whether `'y'` is in `data_period`, this should actually be `>= 0`, since `0` is a valid index.

If you only care about membership,

```
if 'y' in data_period:
```

If you care about membership past the first position (which is what you're currently doing),

```
if 'y' in data_period[1:]:
```

### Return paths

Omitting a few intermediate statements,

```
        if data_period.find( 'y' ) > 0:
            if years >= 1:
                return bool( True )

        elif data_period.find( 'w' ) > 0:
            if weeks >= 4:
                return bool( True )
        else:
            return bool( False )
```

doesn't do what you think it does. This actually has a tri-valued return, potentially `True`, `False` or `None`. `None` will be returned if (for example) you successfully parse `years` but `years == 0`.

An easy way to fix this is

```
        if data_period.find( 'y' ) > 0:
            return years >= 1

        elif data_period.find( 'w' ) > 0:
            return weeks >= 4

        return False
```

### Loop like a native

```
        for i in range( 0, len( output ) ):
            if output[ i ] # ...
            add_traffic( output[ i + 1 ], output[ i ] )
```

can be

```
        for i, this_output in enumerate(output):
            if this_output # ...
            next_output = output[i + 1]
            add_traffic(next_output, this_output)
```

### Direct None checks

```
        if str( interface ) != 'None':
```

should probably be

```
if interface is not None:
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and advice, really helpful.